# ASP.NET Identity in real IT industry situations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Regarding ASP.NET Identity: how often is ASP.NET Identity used in real situation website projects?

We were only taught this in our studies and was wondering is there anything other options other any ASP.NET Identity when using Visual Studio and that is better.

Comment: I don't know how Visual Studio relates to this, but of course you can do your authentication however you want. You're not limited to a single way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net Identity is the latest library by Microsoft and before it, we have been using Asp.Net Membership Provider and Web Security.

Since Asp.Net identity is built on OWIN, and working nice with Asp.Net Core, I don't see any other option to be used or offered by Microsoft.

You can use it for Forms Authentication, OAuth, Integration with Most of Social Identity Provider and Azure Active Directory.

I would say, it is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use MembershipReboot too, it is also good library for authentication in ASP.NET.

link: https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot